# extracting row values from a single table with a condition

Tags: sql-server-2008

I do have a table contains 3 columns like

```
ID   Name    RID
1    xx      4
2    yy      3
3    zz      2
4    aa      1
```

Now I want the result as

```
ID   Name  Rname
1    xx    aa
```

based on the RID it will refer to the ID column and brings the value of Name column as Rname. Please help me the query.

Comment: @Giorgi, I need a query for the above result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the desired result:

```
select t1.ID, t1.Name, t2.Name as Rname
from Table t1
join Table t2 on t1.RID = t2.ID
where t1.ID = 1
```

Comment: Have you cross checked the result  @Giorgi

Comment: It is giving me an error as The multi-part identifier "t.RID" could not be bound.

Comment: There was a minor mistake here `join Table t2 on t.RID = t2.ID`. Change to `join Table t2 on t1.RID = t2.ID`. Updated.

Comment: Is there any shorter way other than the joins @Giorgi

Comment: You can do like `select t1.ID, t1.Name, (SELECT Name FROM TABLE t2 WHERE t1.RID = t2.ID) as Rname
from Table t1
where t1.ID = 1` but I dont think it is much shorter

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a self join:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name AS name, b.name AS rname
FROM   mytable a
JOIN   mytable b ON a.rid = b.id AND a.rid > b.rid
```

Comment: Above query will give null result but try this it will give exact one     ''SELECT a.id, a.name AS name, b.name AS rname
FROM   mytable a
JOIN   mytable b ON a.rid = b.id AND a.rid > b.rid''

Comment: @Prince, arg, stupid typo. Thanks for noticing! (fixed)

Comment: Let me thanking you first to replay my query, and actually I thought I wanna remind you that it is a small typo mistake but I can't, thats why I just re posted, thanks